# Change code during runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime

[There is an old video of Notch debugging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BES9EKK4Aw4) and testing his code and while doing so he simply pauses his game, makes his code modifications, and resume his game with the new changes.

[I found this old post explaining how he does it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135350/how-to-debug-change-java-code-while-the-program-is-running), but I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to Visual Studio 2012.

I know that you can enable Edit and Continue but this is a lot more restricted in the sense that you can't edit anything you want and you need to set a breakpoint. So Edit and Continue is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: java is almost geared to hot-code swap, the JVM has hooks for it (though with some limitations), I doubt that the .NET architecture can do as well

Comment: Hm that's too bad. It's such a cool and handy feature

Comment: I guess the domain of both forums cross at some point. Feel free to flag this to be moved if you want to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that you can enable Edit and Continue but this is a lot more restricted in the sense that you can't edit anything you want …

Yes, there are some things that you can't edit with Edit and Continue. But that's the best you can do with the current tools, I don't think there is a way around that.

> … and you need to set a breakpoint

No, you don't. You can use the “pause” button in VS (real name Break All), edit your code and then let it continue executing.

Comment: Didn't know of the pause button. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

.NET's edit and continue is nowhere near as good as that provided by Visual C++, Visual Basic or any dynamic (ie script) languages which is a pity.

If you can live with the [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx) (having to break execution, no 64-bit support unless you are v4.5.1+, no lambda/linq changes, changing active statements, and a few others) then you should be ok to do pretty much the same. I find though, that I always end up wanting to change something that's unsupported :(

The big alternative is to use unit tests - in that, if you have enough tests you do not need to go debugging into your code at all. I think its debatable whether you save more time or not, and maybe it depends on the programmer style which suits you better.